# Partial black background in iphone safari

Tags: iphone, css, safari, background-color

a few days ago I realized that my homepage `www.blog-it-solutions.de` will not correctly represented in iPhone Safari.

This is how it looks:

[image: iPhone Safari screen]

Has anyone an idea what happend?

Comment: Try validating your HTML using the W3C validator (http://validator.w3.org), fix any errors, and perhaps it will then work as expected.

Comment: The homepage is already XHTML 1.0 valid.

Comment: You should also post a screenshot of what you would expect !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a png which is somewhere in the page, i've had the same problem on my website and I solved it by converting the png into jpeg and it worked

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer. I converted the *.png to *.gif and now the page is correctly represented. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may either:

1. Re-save the files as other image files (JPEG, GIF)
2. If it is a gradient image, then you may use [CSS3 Gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to achieve the effect.